# Making h:panelGroup clickable, and send back repeated variable

Tags: ajax, jsf

I need to make a `panelGrid` (one of man that are populated from a list of objects) clickable, and then send the item associated with it to the backing bean.

My HTML so for:

```
<ui:repeat var="searchItem" value="#{bean.filteredSearchItems}" varStatus="searchResult">
    <h:panelGrid>
        <!-- I get some info here from the searchResult object -->
    </h:panelGrid>
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="{bean.clickFlight}" />
    <f:param name="lfi" value="#{searchResult.index}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

I know that (in my backing bean) I need a function called `clickSearchItem()` that can handle the ajax call, so to test all of this, I did the following in my backing bean:

```
public void clickFlight()
{
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String lfi = req.getParameter("lfi");

if (lfi == null)
    log.info("LFI WAS RETURNED AS NULL :(");

    log.info("HOPEFULLY AN INDEX OF SOME SORT!: " + lfi);
}
```

Nothing is getting logged - the click doesn't register. Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, that was completely my fault(has been corrected now) - I asked the question at the end of a long and exhausting day. I wasn't consentrating. I am using HTMLPanelGrid tags because HTMLPanelGroup does not implement ClientBehaviourHolder.

I have, in the meantime, tried to get the code working, but with no success. Am I using the `ajax` and `param` tags in the right place?

Comment: Fair enough. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<f:ajax>` needs to be nested into a component implementing `ClientBehaviorHolder`. If you intend to use `<h:panelGrid>` (which generates a HTML `<table>`) for that, then you should be nesting the `<f:ajax>` in the component itself.

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="{bean.clickFlight}" />

    <!-- I get some info here from the searchResult object -->
</h:panelGrid>
```

The `<f:param>` is only recognized by renderer of `<h:outputFormat>` and `<h:commandXxx>`. Provided that you're targeting a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss 6/7, etc) which thus supports EL 2.2, then you can just pass it as method argument instead:

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="{bean.clickFlight(searchResult.index)}" />

    <!-- I get some info here from the searchResult object -->
</h:panelGrid>
```

you can even pass the whole object if preferred:

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="{bean.clickFlight(searchResult)}" />

    <!-- I get some info here from the searchResult object -->
</h:panelGrid>
```

An alternative, if you need `<f:param>` per se, would be to use `<h:commandLink>` instead.

```
<h:commandLink>
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="{bean.clickFlight(searchResult)}" />
    <f:param name="lfi" value="#{searchResult.index}" />

    <h:panelGroup>
        <!-- I get some info here from the searchResult object -->
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Thanks. Normally when catching an ajax call with a java function in the backing bean, you'd accept an AjaxBehaviourEvent. When sending an object back with the ajax value, what happens to said AjaxBehaviourEvent? Do I still need to capture it, or can I just capture the object I sent back?

Comment: The `()` completely overrides the default signature. So, `listener="#{bean.checkFlight()}"` expects a `public void checkFlight()` and `listener="#{bean.checkFlight(searchResult)}"` expects a `public void checkFlight(SearchResult searchResult)`, etc.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the answer, and sorry for the horrible question - will do my best not to let that happen again