# Sending a redirect from inside an ajax listener method

Tags: ajax, jsf, redirect

This question is closely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18515372/1073118) one (which has been answered).

Throughout my project, I navigate between screens using JSF command buttons, where the action attribute would point to a function that returns a string. The string is the new screen's name e.g.

```
<h:commandButton value="Select" action="#{searchResultsBundledBean.selectFlight}">
</h:commandButton>
```

`selectFlight` would return a string, e.g. `selected-flight-review` which would direct the user to `selected-flight-review.xhtml`

For mobile purposes I had to make a `panelGrid` clickable using an ajax call, e.g.

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{searchResultsBundledBean.clickFlight(lowFareBundledSearchItem)}"/>
 </h:panelGrid
```

This works, I've tested it, and the correct result is returned(Tested with logging it right before it's returned)

However, no redirection takes place. The ajax call doesn't do it yet. How do I make it redirect to another screen? I don't have to send through any variables, I just need the new screen to be displayed. Should I use something other than ajax(I would prefer not to), or is there some way to make this work the way it is now?

Comment: Have you tried with `?faces-redirect=true` appended? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7928396/1199132

Comment: Yea, already tried that. It returns the modifed string(with the redirect appended), but it doesn't actually do anything with it. The problem I'm stuck with here is that the ajax isn't associated with a commandLink or commandButton

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can redirect the response from the backing bean:

```
public void clickFlight(Item lowFareBundledSearchItem) throws IOException {
    // ...
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("selected-flight-review.xhtml");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: It's better to redirect via JSF's NavigationHandler using outcomes, instead of using servlet level raw URL redirection.

Comment: According to the JSF specs, you have to call FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete(); after redirection using external context.

Comment: The [ExternalContext javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect-java.lang.String-) says: "Redirect a request to the specified URL, and cause the responseComplete() method to be called on the FacesContext instance for the current request."  This makes me think the explicit call to `responseComplete()` is not necessary.  There's some other text in that link about how the call to redirect works under Ajax.

Answer (score -2):

Just add in your backing bean
 return "selected-flight-review";
You don't need to add (.xhtml)
Or if you wanna redirect
 return "selected-flight-review? Faces-redirect=true";

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The question asks clearly about an ajax listener method, not an command action method. You can only return a navigation case in a command action method. The OP even explicitly mentioned this in his question.