# JSF, Primefaces Tree onNodeClick with GET

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I have a tree (p:tree) and I would like to GET (no POST) the whole page after each node selection. How can I do it ?

```
<p:tree ... >
 <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{tree.onNodeSelect}"/>
 <p:treeNode ... >
  ....
</p:tree>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Kukeltje I found no option to try. Ajax is Client side and can not ask something from server.

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589616/sending-a-redirect-from-inside-an-ajax-listener-method ???

Answer (score 0):

It does remember the selected nod `programmatically`, but it doesn't `reflect visually` on the tree, that means the tree doesn't `highlight` the selected node once it was re-rendered.

and another issue is that, after re-render the `<p:tree>` component, the tree will be totally folded up.

> I think [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/issues/505) is related..

Comment: Primefaces has migrated their issues to github